# How do I reference a thread in a separate java class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am calling a function in a java class from a Thread declared and started in another java class. How do I interrupt / terminate the thread that called the function from within the function?

Comment: What did you try? What doesn't work? Where is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Thread.currentThread()` to get a reference of the running thread, and then call `interrupt()` to interrupt it.

If you want the Thread to stop executing, just use `return`, so that the call stack will return to the `run()` method of thread. And the Thread will terminated itself when `run()` is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the static methods of class Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) to do something with the current thread. But the question is if you *should*. Usually the implementing class of a thread itself should be responsible for its threading behavior. A 3rd class should not interfere.

Comment: which static method(s) in particular do you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Throw an Exception that the thread calling you does not catch (for example a suitable RuntimeException) and it will cause the thread to exit.

Comment: Or throw an exception that it **does** catch in the `run`method, and handles it by returning from the `run` method.